# sql unique constrait with a custom value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table:

```
id emp_id company role
1  3      1       0
2  2      1       0
3  1      1       1
```

I need to restrict adding 2 employees for a company with `role = 1`. Like unique key for company & role, but only for role = 1;

In other words, `INSERT INTO table (emp_id, company, role) (4, 1, 1)` must fail.

The only way to do it in my head - use triggers. Are there another way?

Comment: Make a composite key with more then One columns, that will solve your issue, (No need to use triggers)

Comment: @securedeveloper but he wants to allow creating multiple rows with `role = 0`..

Comment: "Are there another way?" not without chaning table design that I can think of... @securedeveloper how?  composite key on company role would prevent company 1 from having 2 role 0's... which is allowed... `insert where not exists (company with role 1) same for update...`  but this doesn't enforce it... trigger is the only way to enforce it as no constraint or composite key could without changing the table design.

Comment: Like below posted answer,

Answer (score 1):

ONe way to do this in MySQL is to change the `role` so it contains 1 or `NULL` rather than `or`0`.  A unique index ignores`NULL`s, so you can do:

```
create unique index idx_table_company_role on table(company, role);
```

You can then create a view on the table, if you want to see 0 and 1:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, (case when role = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as newrole
    from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `filtered index`

```
create unique index [Indexname]
on [Yourtable](company,role)
where [role] = 1
```

Comment: MySQL does not support partial indexes

Comment: ohhh didn't know about it. Sql server has this feature